# Jackson serializes a private field with field autodection off

Tags: java, serialization, jackson, resteasy

I'm using resteasy version 3.0.11, with jaxb and jackson 2.0 as serialization providers. I have a service which looks like this:

```
@Path("/path")
@IgnoreMediaTypes("application/*+json")
public interface MyService {
    @GET
    @Path("/test")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @IgnoreMediaTypes("application/*+json")
    MyData getData();
}
```

and this is MyData class:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class MyData implements JsonSerializable {
    @JsonProperty
    private int a;
    private int b;
}
```

JsonSerializable interface:

```
@JsonAutoDetect(
  fieldVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE, 
  getterVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE, 
  setterVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE, 
  isGetterVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE, 
  creatorVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
@JsonSerialize(include = JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
public interface JsonSerializable {}
```

My problem is that when I call this service with localhost/path/test, b property of MyData class is also serialized:

```
{"a":0,"b":0}
```

even, JsonSerializeble Interface has fieldVisibility set to NONE. Tried already all that I could with no success. Any help with this problem?

Comment: your field is not private as title says, its having default access modifier

Comment: @Panther, sorry, I missed modifiers... updated the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect, the JAXB annotations take precedence over the Jackson annotations. This depends on how Jackson is configured (see the [documentation](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJAXBAnnotations) for details).

`@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)` is basically the same as `@JsonAutoDetect(
  fieldVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)`. Remove the `@XmlAccessorType` annotation and you should be good to go.

Comment: I know it works if to remove XmlAccesorType... but that shouldn't happen according to documentation since I used IgnoreMediaTypes

Comment: From what I read in the documentation `@IgnoreMediaTypes` prevents RESTEasy from using its own JAXB provider. But if Jackson is the alternative provider and it is configured to handle JAXB annotations as well, than my answer would still be valid. However, this is obviously not the answer you were looking for.

Comment: I think last comment is the answer to my question, so I'll accept it. Can you please provide my how I should configure Jackson to take precedence on json annotations? I didn't enabled any jaxb support in it.